# AWS ECS service monitoring (using multiple endpoints)

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-ecs, health-check

We are currently deploying multiple instances (a front-end, a back-end, a database, etc..). All are deployed and configured using a CloudFormation script so we can deploy our solution quickly. One of our central server has multiple connections to other services and, for some, we open very simple REST endpoints that reply with 200 or 500 if the server can connect to another service or the database (get on /dbConnectionStatus for example).

We would like to have perform calls on those endpoints periodically and have a view on these. A little bit like the health check but **without restarting** the instance in case of trouble and possibly **multiple endpoints** to check on a service.

Is there an AWS service that can achieve that? If not what alternative do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AWS CloudWatch Synthetic Monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries.html) can do what you want. By default it will just perform checks against your endpoints, and log the success or failure, without triggering a redeployment or something like a load balancer health check would.